# How to Write a matrix Laurent polynomial $A_{-5}t^{-5} + A_{-4}t^{-4} + ...+ A_0 + A_1 t + A_2 t^2....$ in mathematica

Tags: matrix, polynomials

I need to write in mathematica programming language a matrix Laurent Polynomial
$$ T = \sum_{i=-5}^{5} A_i t ^i $$
where the $A_i$ are $n \times n$ matrices (I want the entries to be symbolic) which can take entries in $\mathbb{C}$.
So that I can get the conditions on the entries of the $A_i$ such that $T^2$ and $T^3$ are just polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$.

Comment: Have you seen `Sum`?

Comment: `Array[a, {11, n, n}] . t^Range[-5,5]`, perhaps, assuming `n` is a positive `Integer`. There a bias in the index $i$: $(A_i)_{rc}$ is represented by `a[i+6, r, c]`.

Comment: small note: I think the `Dot` needs to be reversed in MichaelE2's answer; also note that you can eliminate the bias/offset by taking advantage of the second argument of `Array`, which gives the starting indices: `(t^Range[-5, 5]) . Array[a, {11, n, n}, {-5, 1, 1}]`

Comment: @thorimur Thanks.  Was answering from a phone and didn't check.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, first define a function that creates the Ai with symbolic elements:

```
n = 2;
A[i_] := Array[(Subscript[a[i], #1, #2]) &, {n, n}]
```

The rest is trivial, simply sum it up:

```
Sum[A[i] t^i, {i, -5, 5}]
```

An example for n=2. Note that result is a matrix where every element is a Laurent series:

[image]